# Alexa: How to know where large responses are interrupted?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

My skill has some intents which give out very large reponses (text). So there is a good chance the user might want to interrupt it and listen to the remaining part of the response later. I want to make the intent continue from where it left off (I guess I will have to use user state management). Is there a way for the backend to know where it was interupted? or even better, is there a way to send the response line by line so that the backend exactly knows which line was read out last?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to find where the speech was interrupted nor you can send multiple responses line by line. However, you could calculate the time difference between when the response was sent and the interrupted request was received. And based on the time difference you could roughly determine where was it interrupted. Again, this is not an accurate way, it just a hack and you should keep in mind the network latency.

When you send the response, include response generated timestamp in `sessionAttributes`, so that you can use it to verify time difference.